# how to get newtonsoft to camelcase object properties

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got the following code which newtonsoft camelcases the top level of properties but not the properties passed in as Object.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Body { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
public void Test()
{
    var json = @"
        {
            'Id': 2,
            'Name': 'Foo',
            'Body': {
                'ShipmentId':'6983136',
                'PickupDate':'2019-07-26T17:14:11Z',
                'OrderNumbers':['9638063']
            }
        }";

    var myEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(json);
    var camelSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    var endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent, camelSettings);
    Console.WriteLine(endJson);
}
```

This outputs:

> {"id":2,"name":"Foo","body":{"ShipmentId":"6983136","PickupDate":"2019-07-26T17:14:11Z","OrderNumbers":["9638063"]}}

How do I get it to camelcase the properties inside of body.

Comment: Does it actually set the `id` to lowercase like that and the rest pascal cased?

Comment: Yup. It fails to lowercase everything inside the body property.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm

Comment: why not use: 
endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: @Csharls - how does the indenting help with casing?

Comment: @BrendanGreen sorry i saw a wrong example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution would be to use ExpandoObject. For example,

```
var myEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json); // Deserialize as ExpandoObject
var camelSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent, camelSettings);
```

Please note that above code Deserialize the json as ExpandoObject instead of Event. This would produce as endJson as

```
{"id":2,"name":"Foo","body":{"shipmentId":"6983136","pickupDate":"2019-07-26T17:14:11Z","orderNumbers":["9638063"]}}
```

Comment: Nice! And I would like to add here that the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method is overloaded. So in case you would like to have camelCase *and* Formatting.Indented, do this: var endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent, Formatting.Indented, camelSettings);

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before. It is because of type object.

You can get fix it by creating a class for body or follow this link 
https://andrewlock.net/serializing-a-pascalcase-newtonsoft-json-jobject-to-camelcase/#3-convert-a-pascalcase-jobject-to-camelcase

If you follow the link. You have to convert it first into JObject using below code

```
var myEvent = JObject.Parse(json);  
var endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent.ToCamelCaseJToken(), camelSettings);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when I want to send data for an Angular mat-table component

I had to send an object that contain an array of object and  other value for the component

Array of Cities

```
var villeT = from c in _context.Cities.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
            select new Ville_DTO()
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                Lat = c.Lat,
                Lon = c.Lon,
                Population = c.Population,
                CountryName = _context.Countries.FirstOrDefault(p => c.CountryId == p.Id).Name
            };
```

and the object to be sent

```
PageVille_DTO page = new PageVille_DTO()
        {   Data = villeT,
            PageIndex = pageIndex,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            TotalCount = nbRecord,
            TotalPages = totalPage,
            HasPreviousPage = hasPrevious,
            HasNextPage = hasNext
        };
```

Using JsonConvert

```
            string pageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
        return Ok(pageJson);
```

Sample of the result

> {
> "data": [
> {
> "id": 1,
> "name": "Tokyo",
> "lat": 35.6897,
> "lon": 139.6922,
> "population": 37732000,
> "countryName": "Japan"
> },
> {
> "id": 2,
> "name": "Jakarta",
> "lat": -6.1750,
> "lon": 106.8275,
> "population": 33756000,
> "countryName": "Indonesia"
> }
> ],
> "pageIndex": 0,
> "pageSize": 2,
> "totalCount": 44691,
> "totalPages": 22345,
> "hasPreviousPage": false,
> "hasNextPage": false
> }