# Setting Newtonsoft.Json options in Xamarin forms app

Tags: json, xamarin

In .NET Core applications, I can set the default behavior of the Newtonsoft.Json deserializer by doing this:

```
_ = services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

This tells JSON that all JSON fields should be camel-case. My question is: how do I tell Xamarin to map the camel-case fields back to the pascal case field names I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following code?it would be to use ExpandoObject. For example,

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

   var myEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json); // Deserialize as ExpandoObject
   var camelSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
   var endJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent, camelSettings);
```

Here is similar thread: [how to get newtonsoft to camelcase object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263017/how-to-get-newtonsoft-to-camelcase-object-properties)

Comment: I would just add this to everywhere I deserialize, yes? I think this could be a valid solution. I'm just surprised that there isn't some universal setting for the JSON deserializer.

Comment: Yes, I do not find settings as well.