# .NET 6 - Change Json Property Casing

Tags: json, .net, system.text.json, .net-6.0, camelcasing

How can I change the casing of the property names of a json **without performing model binding**?
JsonElement serialization ignores PropertyNaming JsonSerializer options as is also confirmed here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61843
The suggested use of JsonNode/JsonObject results in the same behavior.

Any hints how I can accomplish this?

As example I want to change this:

```
{
    "MyPoperty" : 5,
    "MyComplexProperty" : {
        "MyOtherProperty": "value",
        "MyThirdProperty": true
    }
}
```

to this:

```
{
    "myPoperty" : 5,
    "myComplexProperty" : {
        "myOtherProperty": "value",
        "myThirdProperty": true
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: seems like your question has already an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570189/is-there-a-built-in-way-of-using-snake-case-as-the-naming-policy-for-json-in-asp/

Comment: No - that solution requires model binding. The serialization does not take naming policy or custom converters into account when serializing JsonElements.

Answer (score -1):

## I think you try to use `Newtonsoft json`

```
class Person
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

## coding

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.UserName = "Bob";
    person.Age = 20;

    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, serializerSettings);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

## output

```
{"userName":"Bob","age":20}
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this with the new System.Text.Json instead?

Comment: There are no better solutions in addition to this.

Comment: By the way, I need a solution without model binding.  With model binding, it works in both NewtonSoft and System.Text.Json.

Comment: I tried to use NewtonSoft to parse  characters directly.

Comment: Perhaps there is still a method to be realized, but it is more troublesome

Answer (score -1):

## not depend on `Newtonsoft json`  but in the case of multi-layer objects

```
var json = @"{""ShouldWindUpAsCamelCase"":""does it?""}";
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var item in obj)
{
    dic.Add(item.Key.FirstCharToLower(), item.Value);
}
var serialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(dic);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
```

## FirstCharToLower() function

```
 public static string FirstCharToLower(this string input)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return input;
            string str = input.First().ToString().ToLower() + input.Substring(1);
            return str;
        }
```

#output

```json
{"shouldWindUpAsCamelCase":"does it?"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this will also not work. This basically binds to a flat dictionary. So it doesn't allow complex objects.
I did find a solution after all, but it is far from ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263017/how-to-get-newtonsoft-to-camelcase-object-properties - uses newtonsoft and expandoObject.

Comment: Well LET me try a few more ways and I'll let you know